# IIS Server не включается

Tags: iis, iis-express, iis-10

Раньше включал службы IIS.На новой Windows убрал автоматическое обновление. Позже попытался включить IIS, но они не запускаются. Мало того- многие другие сервисы и расширения тоже не ставятся, тоесть возможно причина не в них. Скачал и установил  IIS Express, но всёравно пишет следующую картину....
Походу слетело что-то глобальное, так как IIS не включается ни в каких комбинациях.
Подскажите,в чём может быть дело? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]